# Add additional processing in an automake build for one object

Tags: automake

I'm trying to make a small change to an automake build.

The system to modify uses `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` inputs.
For a single object file within one subdirectory I have to invoke
a script before compiling, to patch config info into the build.

I don't see the right location to allow such pre-processing
ahead of compiling this specific C file. What I've tried is
to insert an additional target into

```
all: all-am
```

But this seems not to be the way to go and in addition I wasn't able
to figure how to overload this generated line.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add in a special target for the object file in question in your Makefile.am.  Something like:

```
file.o: file.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c file.c
    modification.sh file.o
```

This should cause `modification.sh` to be run on the object file whenever it gets built.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. What I found in between were the automake targets
BUILD_SOURCES
all-local

This way I can inject similar things.

Comment: This is probably the right way, but not that if your modification script fails, it will leave an unpatched but seemingly up to date file.o lying around.  It might be better to chain the commands like file.c -> file.o.tmp -> file.o.